# Why does the ng-repeat directive create a child scope?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

**Question:** Why does the ng-repeat directive create a child scope?

I don't understand why this is the case.  Creating a new scope makes sense to an extent if you  explicitly create a child controller, but why would it automatically create one for every ng-repeat?

I guess the reason it confuses me is because if you create a loop in JS, that doesn't mean the  code outside the loop can't access any of the variables inside of it.

Example:

```
for(var x=0; x<10; x++) {
   var y = x
}
alert(y);
```

Comment: It creates an isolated new scope instead of a child scope. You cannot inherit from the parent. for loop and ng-repeat are different ideas because ngRepeat instantiates template per iteration which a for loop does not. Definition of [ngRepeat](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/docs/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) will make it clear.

Comment: It's true that JavaScript does not have block-scoped variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DOM is not javascript. The items in the collection you are `ng-repeat`ing over need to be bound to separate scopes that are bound to the repeated DOM elements and creates a tree of scopes that mirror structure of the page (somewhat)

ex, this markup:

```
<body ng-app="myapp">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
        <p>{{ item.name }}</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

will produce something like the DOM on the left and scope on the right:

```
body            rootScope
    div             scope       
        p
    div             scope
        p
```

(somewhat approximate for illustration)

Comment: This makes sense, I guess I didn't think of it as needing to match up scope with the structure of the DOM.  I guess allowing for parent -> children access from scopes can cause issues with resolving variable names because two different child scopes could have the same variable names and it wouldn't be able to resolve it.  Whereas going from child -> parent wouldn't every cause a problem.

Answer (score 2):

From [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) (with my emphasis):

> The ngRepeat directive instantiates a template once per item from a
>   collection. Each template instance gets **its own scope**, where the given
>   loop variable is set to the current collection item, and $index is set
>   to the item index or key.

Seems pretty straightforward, doesn't it?

Comment: I understand that it creates it's own scope, but I was just trying to understand why.

Comment: **Why** as a question does not makes sense. You can ask **what for** and the above paragraph explains it.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript was written by a single person in 10 days. In almost every other language, loops create a separate scope and your code example wouldn't compile or you'd end up with null/none for y in your last line.

Comment: What is the benefit of creating a new scope for loops?

Comment: @glandrum101 - not just for loops. For any **block**.  It improves scope granularity.  In languages with Garbage Collection allows for earlier disposal.

Comment: @PM77-1 That makes sense, I guess it would be a nightmare to have to worry about what every other sibling block/scope variable names were anytime you created a new block/scope, since you wouldn't be able to have duplicate variable names otherwise the parent scope wouldn't be able to resolve these references.